# run composer update with exec

Tags: php, composer-php

I try this to make an update via a PHP function

```
public function update() {
    $cmd = 'composer update -d ' . static::$root;
    exec( $cmd, $output );
    var_dump( $output );
}
```

the result is :

```
array(0) { } NULL
```

If you make that directly in the console I have an update and result to update a library like phpmailer for example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following:

```
exec('composer update 2>&1', $msg); // update dependencies

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($msg);
echo '</pre>';
```

This should give you the desired output.

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`. Composer status/progress info is purely informational(not something you'd pipe to another application), so it goes on `stderr`.

Comment: Tk. I have a result : array(1) { [0]=> string(59) "sh: 1: /home/www/clicshopping_test/shop/: Permission denied" } my composer.json is in 777 and composer.lock in 644 . Do you have an idea ?